# Do matter and antimatter undergo relativistic effects identically?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, experimental-physics, antimatter

As far as I know, the Dirac equation describes quantum particles moving at relativistic speeds. Since the dirac equation predicts antimatter as well, we should expect matter and antimatter to undergo relativistic effects identically. But has this been experimentally proven?

Comment: Particle accelerators would not work if relativity did not work as expected. Some use anti-proton beams. These work.

Answer (score 1):

There's no evidence that matter and antimatter experience different relativistic effects. As [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_searches_for_Lorentz_violation) puts it, "No Lorentz violations have been measured thus far, and exceptions in which positive results were reported have been refuted or lack further confirmations."

But people are searching. See Wiki for [Antimatter tests of Lorentz violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter_tests_of_Lorentz_violation).